# .NET Configuration API without dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core console app which loads my config file like so:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

Configuration = configBuilder.Build();
```

Most of the examples I've seen simply stop there, so I assume they then pass Configuration around throughout the entire app? (or inject it with IOC)

In the old days I'd simply do ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] from any class anywhere, but I'd like to use the new appsettings.json approach. Is the easy "global" access of configuration now discouraged?

I don't think IOC is suitable in my case, as my Main() method immediately creates lots of class instances using 'new'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted practice is to inject the config as `IConfiguration` to your service.

If you don't mind the risk of shooting yourself in the foot, you could manually create a global static class with the built configuration initialized at the start and use it everywhere, but please note that it's basically a heresy from the OOP perspective.

As a note: if your `Main` method creates a lot of things using `new`, maybe it shouldn't? You could use an IoC container and call `container.Resolve<IService>()` instead of `new Service(/*...*/)`. If you considered a little bit of refactoring you could set up DI properly (which is worthwhile if you ever plan to unit-test the thing (NOTE: you should unit-test the thing)).

Answer (score 0):

This will helpful for you. it's working for me.

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionStringName)
    {
        string basePath = "";
        try
        {
            var env = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
            basePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()

            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            return Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful for you

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionStringName)
{
    string basePath = "";
    try
    {
        var env = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
        basePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        return Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation around the code will get you more brownie points and make your answer more useful for future generations